# Use of loose schemas in Clojure with clj-schema

Tags: clojure, clj-schema

I want to create what I believe is called a *loose* schema to verify the contents of a Clojure map.

The [`clj-schema`](https://github.com/runa-dev/clj-schema) examples led me to believe that I only needed to specify `:loose` as the first argument to `def-map-schema`. However this does not seem to work.

Consider the following test (using midje):

```
(def-map-schema loose-schema :loose [[:id] Number])

(fact (empty? (validation-errors loose-schema {:id 1})) => true)            ; OK
(fact (empty? (validation-errors loose-schema {:id "string"})) => false)    ; OK
(fact (empty? (validation-errors loose-schema {:id 1 :foo "bar"})) => true) ; NO!
```

The third test produces:

> "Path [:foo] was not specified in the schema."

How can I make the schema ignore extraneous map entries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the arguments around the wrong way.

The schema returned by `def-map-schema` was not actually loose:

```
(loose-schema? loose-schema)
=> false
```

Instead of:

```
(def-map-schema loose-schema :loose [[:id] Number])
```

The correct form is:

```
(def-map-schema :loose loose-schema [[:id] Number])
```